# on ubuntu, internal speakers don't work, but aux jack works

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, mac

audio only plays on aux jack or bluetooth.

`lspci`:
audio:
Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 0a)
Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller

Comment: Is there a reason for the mac tag?

Comment: yes. it is taking place/running on mac computer.

Comment: Then please edit the question and add some details. Is Ubuntu the only OS on the machine?

Comment: no. the internal disc is mac os

Comment: on mac os the internal speakers and aux jack work.

Comment: ubuntu is running off of micro sd card on usb.